# Karma + AngularAMD: troubleshooting error "angularAMD not initialized."

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-amd

Struggling here, spent hours on this already. Karma test keeps saying:

`Error: angularAMD not initialized.  Need to call angularAMD.bootstrap(app) first.`

[Take a look at the build on runnable.com](http://runnable.com/VEAM4S-V4I1yWD7r). Hit `Run` button or type `gulp` in the terminal to run the karma test. Should see the error as shown above.

Anyone want to take a stab at figuring out where I went wrong? I'm already calling `angularAMD.bootstrap(app)` in `test/app.js` so I don't know why karma can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution available via: https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD/issues/103

Updated [runnable.com app](http://runnable.com/VEAM4S-V4I1yWD7r/) with working examples.